# Raspberry Pi GPIO pin layout + Cooking Hacks Shield

Tags: arduino

I am studying the schematic diagram of the Raspberry Pi to Arduino shield from cooking hacks and I noticed that there is an inconsistency in the labeling of the pins. So, this gives me two questions. 
Top view of the shield:

[image]

Bottom view of the shield:

[image]

(Both photos taken from their website)

I was creating my own guide for the pin layouts and where they go so that it will be easier and faster to check later on. So this image shows the bottom connection of the shield(left) that attaches to the GPIO ports of the RPi(right). I also marked up to where the shield takes up the GPIO ports(red).
[image]

So finally, my questions are:

1. If you look at GPIO pins 17,21,22; then look to where it connects to the RPi which is labeled 17,27,22 correspondingly. Is this just a typo on cooking hack's end?
2. Do pins like 14,15,18,23,24 and the rest make a direct connection? If for example i connect a wire on the SDA pin on the shield, is it like i'm connecting directly to the GPIO02(SDA1, I2C) of the raspberry pi?

This is the page for the shield:
https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/raspberry-pi-to-arduino-shields-connection-bridge

Answer (score 2):

1. The shield is designed for [Revision 1 of the header](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#cite_ref-2), which was slightly different. It should still work with Revision 2 provided you change any references to GPIO 21 in the software to GPIO 27 instead.
2. The schematic should explain where the pins connect to. Look for all instances of nets with the same name.

Comment: So for this case, it just simply connects to GPIO27 where GPIO21 supposedly was? hmm thanks for clearing it out for me.